# Property 'prompt' does not exist on type event

Tags: typescript

I'm using the event listener `beforeinstallprompt` and the event object in the callback does have the property `prompt`. However typescript complains with the above error.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", (event) => {event.prompt()});
```

How can it be fixed?

Comment: You can fix by providing type assertion to the event,
 (event as any).prompt(); // Type assertion to inform TypeScript